# Swift Charts Library, when first Loaded, highlighted value already

Tags: ios, swift

[enter link description here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

I used Charts/danielgindi..
When a graph is selected, the highlight works properly. But what I want is to highlight the center graph on the first screen when no graph is selected.

chartView.highlightValue(x: 3, dataSetIndex: 3, dataIndex: 3)

chartView.highlightValue(Highlight(x: 3, dataSetIndex: 3, stackIndex: 3))

I wrote the code in the same way as above, but it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
 let midPoint = CGPoint(x: chartView.bounds.midX, y: chartView.bounds.midY)
 let h = chartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(midPoint)
 chartView.highlightValue(h, callDelegate: true)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solved the problem.